# MongoDB Aggregation Data

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

I am new to Mongo Aggregation and have this data

```
{
"_id": {

        "$oid": "5654a8f0d487dd1434571a6e"
    },

    "ValidationDate": {
        "$date": "2015-11-24T13:06:19.363Z"
    },

    "DataRaw": " WL 00100100012015-08-28 02:44:17+0000+ 16.81 8.879  1084.00",

    "ReadingsAreValid": true,

    "locationID": " WL 001",

    "Readings": {

        "pH": {
            "value": 8.879
        },

        "SensoreDate": {
            "value": {
                "$date": "2015-08-28T02:44:17.000Z"
            }
        },

        "temperature": {
            "value": 16.81
        },

        "Conductivity": {
            "value": 1084
        }
    },
    "HMAC":"ecb98d73fcb34ce2c5bbcc9c1265c8ca939f639d791a1de0f6275e2d0d71a801"
}
```

My goal is to calculate the average temperature for every two hours interval, then per month, year and week. I have tried various queries but no luck. This is what i have tried so far

```
data.aggregate([{"$unwind":"$Readings"}, 

{"$project":{"HourRecord":{"$hour":"Readings.SensoreDate.value"}, 

"YearRecord":{"$year":"$Readings.SensoreDate.value"}}},

{'$group' : {'_id' : "$locationID", 
'AverageTemp' : { '$avg' : '$Readings.temperature.value'}}}
])
```

and i got an empty results like this

```
{u'ok': 1.0, u'waitedMS': 0L, u'result': [{u'AverageTemp': None, u'_id': None}]}
```

I have tried several other combinations but still got empty results.

The following Queries Return the required result per hour, month etc but how to i group by two hours interval instead of one hour

```
 test_Agg.aggregate([{"$unwind":"$Readings"},
{"$project":{              "HourRecord": { "$hour":"$Readings.SensoreDate.value"},
                           "YearRecord": {"$year":"$Readings.SensoreDate.value"},
                           "MonthRecord": {"$month":"$Readings.SensoreDate.value"},
                           "locationID" : 1,
                           "Readings.pH.value":1,
                           'Readings.temperature.value' : 1}
},
{'$group' : {'_id' :"$HourRecord",
'AverageTemp' : { '$avg' : '$Readings.temperature.value'}}
}])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second pipeline `$project` in the query didn't project the required values used in the subsequent pipelines. Hence, the result was empty.

The required fields have been added in the `$project`. Try the below query.

```
db.temperature.aggregate([{"$unwind":"$Readings"}, 
{"$project":{              "HourRecord": { "$hour":"$Readings.SensoreDate.value"}, 
                           "YearRecord": {"$year":"$Readings.SensoreDate.value"},
                           locationID : 1,
                           'Readings.temperature.value' : 1}
},
{'$group' : {'_id' : "$locationID", 
'AverageTemp' : { '$avg' : '$Readings.temperature.value'}}}                           
]);
```

**Output for the one document provided in the post:-**

```
{
    "_id" : " WL 001",
    "AverageTemp" : 16.81
}
```

Comment: Thanks This worked. I tried this  to group the readings for every hour but how to i do it for every two hours. I have tried some few options but not able to get it.

Comment: Thanks. What should i do inorder to group by every two hours interval rather than $locationID. The query above works for every hour, month,week?